# C++11 regex substring matching

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, substring

I´m looking for a regular expression in C++11 which can match a substring in a string.

Something like:  `"It´s a dark night out there..."` and I´m searching for `ark`

So if a substring is somewhere in a string this expression shall match.
Furthermore i would like to have the option to say that this match should be case sensitive or not.

I´ve already tried this but it doesn´t seem to work...

```
string str = "It´s a dark night out there...";
regex ex ("ark"); 
if (regex_match (str,ex))
    cout << "Match found!";
```

Does anybody know something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) instead of [`regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). The latter tries to match the entire subject string, while the former allows to match substrings.

And here are the possible [flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type), one of which (the first) represents case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help
I´ve corrected it to
`regex ex ("ark");`
and
`if (regex_search (str,ex))`

Comment: @Xenogenesis why the `.*`? if you use `regex_search`, `ark` is enough.

Comment: Sorry, i´m still confused that there is no need for a wildcard

Comment: @Xenogenesis `regex_search` tries the match starting at every single position in the subject string. that means, if **any** substring of your subject matches the supplied pattern, `regex_search` will find it. You can think of `regex_match` as the same, but it "secretly" surrounds your pattern with `^yourpatternhere$`.